# What happens to the rest of the nodes in orientdb?

Tags: graph, functional-programming, orientdb, nosql

Suppose I have a node A->B&C && B->G&H&I && C->D&E&F if i delete C node then what happened to the nodes connected to C in orientdb?
I am just a beginner in orientdb so may be it is a stupid question to ask is there any solution that orient provides otherwise we have graph solutions.

Answer (score 0):

No node will be deleted, but edges from/to the deleted node will be automatically deleted.

Comment: No dangling, a node can exist without any edges.